# How to prevent an animation if a subitem is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple sidebar meny. The idea is that when I click on an item, I want the other menu item's submenus to `slideUp`, therefore hiding them. This works. However I don't want an animation to run if clicking on a sub item.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu-work-sidebar" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-41">Landscape
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-work menu-item-58">Test1
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-42"><a href="#">Portraits</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-work current-menu-item menu-item-57">Test2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47">Still life
  </li>
</ul>
```

And my script like this:

```
$('#work-sidebar').on('click', '.menu-item-type-custom', function() {

    $(this).siblings().children('.sub-menu:visible').slideUp();
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

I've been battling with this for hours now but I just cannot get it to work no matter what I do.. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell jquery to toggle the slide each time you click a menu item, and you need to tell jquery to stop the event propagation when you click the submenu items:

```js
$('#menu-work-sidebar > li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings().children('.sub-menu:visible').slideUp();
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle();
});
$('#menu-work-sidebar > li > ul > li').on('click', function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-work-sidebar" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-41">Landscape
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-work menu-item-58">Test1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-42"><a href="#">Portraits</a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-work current-menu-item menu-item-57">Test2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47">Still life</li>
</ul>
```